# The best way to synchronize animations

Tags: java, animation, javafx, synchronization

```
public class App extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var root = new Pane();
        var button = new Button("Change");
        button.setLayoutX(225);
        button.setLayoutY(300);
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(150, 50, 200, 200);
        var effect = new BoxBlur(0, 0, 1);
        var text = new Text("POKUS");
        text.setLayoutX(230);
        text.setLayoutY(270);
        text.setEffect(effect);
        button.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            event.consume();
            var random = new Random();
            var fill = new FillTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rectangle, (Color) rectangle.getFill(), Color.color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat()));
            var timeline = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
                            new KeyValue(effect.widthProperty(), 10),
                            new KeyValue(effect.heightProperty(), 10)
                    )
            );
            var timeline2 = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
                            new KeyValue(effect.widthProperty(), 0),
                            new KeyValue(effect.heightProperty(), 0)
                    )
            );
            timeline.setOnFinished((event2) -> {
                var number = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
                var word = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                    word += (char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26));
                }
                text.setText(word);
                text.setEffect(effect);
                timeline2.play();
            });
            new ParallelTransition(fill, timeline).play();
        });
        root.getChildren().addAll(button, rectangle, text);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

This demonstrates my problem.

The program only contains a rectangle, text, and a button that runs the animation of the color change of the rectangle and the text change - in both cases randomly.

However, the rectangle animation takes a second and the text animation takes twice a half second.

In addition, at the end of the first text animation, the text must be generated.

The difference is likely to be slight, but I want to ask if it is possible to adjust the time of the second text animation (`timeline2`) to end at the same time as the rectangle animation (`fill`)?

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Running your code, it seems to already work as you say that you want it to (but maybe that is just because I don't understand).

Comment: I misnamed it. (Now I hope it is better) Yes, the code works.
The point is that the `setOnFinished` method is called with a delay.  If you write the current `fill` time at the beginning of this method, it will print more than 500 milliseconds. (up to several tens)
And this deviation I would like to shorten as much as possible.

Comment: A minor technical note is that the JavaFX system works based upon pulses (see the attached [JavaFX architecture document](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm#A1106308) to understand this more).  Each pulse, by default, occurs approx. every 16ms (60fps).  So, expecting a callback from the JavaFX system (which is what an animation frame is), to call precisely every 500ms won't actually happen because the underlying granularity of the timing mechanism for JavaFX is working based upon a clock with 16ms ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Timeline` to animate the `fill` property. Furthermore you don't need to use more than a single timeline to do all the animations:

```
button.setOnAction((event) -> { // better to use ActionEvent to listen to button activation
    event.consume();
    var random = new Random();
    Color currentColor = (Color) rectangle.getFill();
    Color targetColor = Color.color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat());

    var timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rectangle.fillProperty(), currentColor)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
                    evt -> {
                        var number = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
                        var word = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                            word += (char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26));
                        }
                        text.setText(word);
                    },
                    new KeyValue(effect.widthProperty(), 10),
                    new KeyValue(effect.heightProperty(), 10)
            ), new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
                    new KeyValue(effect.widthProperty(), 0),
                    new KeyValue(effect.heightProperty(), 0),
                    new KeyValue(rectangle.fillProperty(), targetColor)
            )
    );
    timeline.play();
});
```